# Get minimal, maximum and selected values

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select min, max and selected rows from the table:

```
SELECT a.staff_id, u.username, a.date, a.role, a.global_scoring 
FROM quartz_quarter2 AS a 
RIGHT JOIN(SELECT staff_id, username FROM users)u ON a.staff_id = u.staff_id,
(SELECT MIN(global_scoring) AS mini, MAX(global_scoring) AS maxi FROM quartz_quarter2 
 WHERE date = '2019' AND role = 'Checker') AS m
WHERE m.maxi = a.global_scoring OR m.mini = a.global_scoring OR a.staff_id = '161'
AND date = '2019' AND role = 'Checker' GROUP BY global_scoring ORDER BY global_scoring;
```

In some cases it works but in some cases it gives me weird output like this for example:

```
| staff_id | username | date |      role     | global_scoring |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|    100   |    Adam  | 2017 | Senior Artist |      1.99      |
|    161   |    John  | 2019 |     Checker   |      3.05      |
|    221   |    Anna  | 2019 |     Checker   |      3.84      |
```

It selects wrong date and role. What can be the problem for this? Is any better way to select min, max and selected id in one query?

Comment: Try to put this expression  `m.maxi = a.global_scoring OR m.mini = a.global_scoring OR a.staff_id = '161'` in brackets. So the final where will be  `WHERE (m.maxi = a.global_scoring OR m.mini = a.global_scoring OR a.staff_id = '161') 
AND date = '2019' AND role = 'Checker' GROUP BY global_scoring ORDER BY global_scoring;`

Comment: @Tirex seems to work. Thanks, please make that an answer and i will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have problem with logical operator order. Put this expression 
`m.maxi = a.global_scoring OR m.mini = a.global_scoring OR a.staff_id = '161'` in brackets.

So the final where will be:
 `WHERE (m.maxi = a.global_scoring OR m.mini = a.global_scoring OR a.staff_id = '161') AND date = '2019' AND role = 'Checker' GROUP BY global_scoring ORDER BY global_scoring;`